# How does Spring achieve IOC with autowiring?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, autowired

I'm a little confused as to how this [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (`IoC`) works in `Spring`.

**Say I have a service class called `UserServiceImpl` that implements the `UserService` interface.**

How would this be `@Autowired`?

And in my `Controllers`, how would I `instantiate` an `instance` of this service?

Would I just do the following?

```
UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();
```

Answer (score 797, accepted):

First, and most important - all Spring beans are managed - they "live" inside a container, called "application context".

Second, each application has an entry point to that context. Web applications have a Servlet, [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) uses a el-resolver, etc. Also, there is a place where the application context is bootstrapped and all beans - autowired. In web applications this can be a startup listener.

Autowiring happens by placing an instance of one bean into the desired field in an instance of another bean. Both classes should be beans, i.e. they should be defined to live in the application context.

What is "living" in the application context? This means that the *context* instantiates the objects, not you. I.e. - you never make `new UserServiceImpl()` - the container finds each injection point and sets an instance there.

In your controllers, you just have the following:

```
@Controller // Defines that this class is a spring bean
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class SomeController {

    // Tells the application context to inject an instance of UserService here
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public void login(@RequestParam("username") String username,
           @RequestParam("password") String password) {

        // The UserServiceImpl is already injected and you can use it
        userService.login(username, password);

    }
}
```

A few notes:

- In your `applicationContext.xml` you should enable the `<context:component-scan>` so that classes are scanned for the `@Controller`, `@Service`, etc. annotations.
- The entry point for a Spring-MVC application is the DispatcherServlet, but it is hidden from you, and hence the direct interaction and bootstrapping of the application context happens behind the scene.
- `UserServiceImpl` should also be defined as bean - either using `<bean id=".." class="..">` or using the `@Service` annotation. Since it will be the only implementor of `UserService`, it will be injected.
- Apart from the `@Autowired` annotation, Spring can use XML-configurable autowiring. In that case all fields that have a name or type that matches with an existing bean automatically get a bean injected. In fact, that was the initial idea of autowiring - to have fields injected with dependencies without any configuration. Other annotations like `@Inject`, `@Resource` can also be used.

Comment: your last point, so in the implmentation of the interface, UserServiceImpl, I annotate with @Service correct?  Great answer, REALLY cleared things up for me.

Comment: is UserService userService the interface?

Comment: yes, UserServiceImpl is annotated with Service, and UserService is the interface

Comment: It's been more than 3 years since last post on this thread, I just jumped on it when looking for similar question. One query i have is, at context instantiation time, it will create only one bean object (Pls correct me if i am wrong). What if i am autowiring same bean twice in my code, will 2nd object be lazily insantiated?

Comment: the default scope is singleton, so you will have only one instance of the bean, which is injected in multiple places. If you explicitly define the scope to be "prototype", then multiple instances will exist, possibly lazy (depending on configuration)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post, it really cleared things up for me. Regarding 'Since it will be the only implementor or UserService, it will be injected.' - what if there's multiple classes that implement Userservice? How does Spring know which implementation it should use?

Comment: if there's one designated as "primary", it uses it. Otherwise it throws an exception

Comment: @Bozho, So everytime the function `login` is called, is a new `userService` being created? Does autowiring in spring relieve the coder from creating a Singleton object?

Comment: no, userService is created only once, it's in singleton-scope

Comment: True, we've compiled some of there in our [Spring Autowiring](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/02/08/spring-autowiring/) article.

Answer (score 71):

Depends on whether you want the annotations route or the bean XML definition route.

Say you had the beans defined in your `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<beans ...>

    <bean id="userService" class="com.foo.UserServiceImpl"/>

    <bean id="fooController" class="com.foo.FooController"/>

</beans>
```

The autowiring happens when the application starts up. So, in `fooController`, which for arguments sake wants to use the `UserServiceImpl` class, you'd annotate it as follows:

```
public class FooController {

    // You could also annotate the setUserService method instead of this
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    // rest of class goes here
}
```

When it sees `@Autowired`, Spring will look for a class that matches the property in the `applicationContext`, and inject it automatically. If you have more than one `UserService` bean, then you'll have to qualify which one it should use.

If you do the following:

```
UserService service = new UserServiceImpl();
```

It will not pick up the `@Autowired` unless you set it yourself.

Comment: So what is the use of defining `bean id` in `applicationContext.xml` . We will have to define the `userService` variable with `UserService` type. So why make entry in `xml` file.

Comment: @viper he is talking about interfacing it  i believe

Answer (score 22):

`@Autowired` is an annotation introduced in Spring 2.5, and it's used only for injection.

For example:

```
class A {

    private int id;

    // With setter and getter method
}

class B {

    private String name;

    @Autowired // Here we are injecting instance of Class A into class B so that you can use 'a' for accessing A's instance variables and methods.
    A a;

    // With setter and getter method

    public void showDetail() {
        System.out.println("Value of id form A class" + a.getId(););
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't compile and is generally incorrect. `@Autowired` does not mean that "you can use all the function(method) and variable in `B` class from class `A`". What it does is brings an instance of `A` into instances of `B`, so you can do `a.getId()` from `B`.

Comment: @dimadima So if he does System.out.println("Value of id form A class" + a.getId());, and not as he has actually done it will be more correct. Please do reply, as this one is intuitively clear to me and as per my current level of understanding is explaining Autowiring.

Comment: autowired annotation is introduced in spring 2.5 http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: For better understadin as I am new to this, will @autowired instantiate the Class A using the default constructor? IF not, how to values get instantiated in a bean or service if we use autowired. I guess if it calls default constructor, why use autowiring in the first place, just do A a = new A(). Please clarify?

Comment: @Sameer By Autowiring dependencies you can save a lot of boilerplate code in your Unit Tests and also Controller, Service and Dao Classes, because the instantiation of the fields come with it automatically. No need to call the constructor.

Comment: Class A is not a Spring bean. How are you auto-wiring it in Class B?

Answer (score 11):

How does `@Autowired` work internally?

Example:

```
class EnglishGreeting {
   private Greeting greeting;
   //setter and getter
}

class Greeting {
   private String message;
   //setter and getter
}
```

.xml file it will look alike if not using `@Autowired`:

```
<bean id="englishGreeting" class="com.bean.EnglishGreeting">
   <property name="greeting" ref="greeting"/>
</bean>

<bean id="greeting" class="com.bean.Greeting">
   <property name="message" value="Hello World"/>
</bean>
```

If you are using `@Autowired` then:

```
class EnglishGreeting {
   @Autowired //so automatically based on the name it will identify the bean and inject.
   private Greeting greeting;
   //setter and getter
}
```

.xml file it will look alike if not using `@Autowired`:

```
<bean id="englishGreeting" class="com.bean.EnglishGreeting"></bean>

<bean id="greeting" class="com.bean.Greeting">
   <property name="message" value="Hello World"/>
</bean>
```

If still have some doubt then go through below live demo

[How does @Autowired work internally ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DljWTxcSjk)

Answer (score 6):

You just need to annotate your service class `UserServiceImpl` with annotation:

```
@Service("userService")
```

Spring container will take care of the life cycle of this class as it register as service.

Then in your controller you can auto wire (instantiate) it and use its functionality:

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;
```

Answer (score 4):

Spring dependency inject help you to remove coupling from your classes.
Instead of creating object like this:

```
UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();
```

You will be using this after introducing DI:

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
```

For achieving this you need to create a bean of your service in your `ServiceConfiguration` file. After that you need to import that `ServiceConfiguration` class to your `WebApplicationConfiguration` class so that you can autowire that bean into your Controller like this:

```
public class AccController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
}
```

You can find a java configuration based POC here 
[example](https://github.com/abdusSalam1/POCs/tree/master/VaadinExample).

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 ways you can create an instance using `@Autowired`.

**1. `@Autowired` on Properties**

The annotation can be used directly on properties, therefore eliminating the need for getters and setters:

```
    @Component("userService")
    public class UserService {

        public String getName() {
            return "service name";
        }
    }

    @Component
    public class UserController {

        @Autowired
        UserService userService

    }
```

In the above example, Spring looks for and injects `userService` when `UserController` is created.

**2. `@Autowired` on Setters**

The `@Autowired` annotation can be used on setter methods. In the below example, when the annotation is used on the setter method, the setter method is called with the instance of `userService` when `UserController` is created:

```
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
            this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

**3. `@Autowired` on Constructors**

The `@Autowired` annotation can also be used on constructors. In the below example, when the annotation is used on a constructor, an instance of `userService` is injected as an argument to the constructor when `UserController` is created:

```
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService= userService;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add @Autowired is not mandatory on the constructor injection.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words Autowiring, wiring links automatically, now comes the question who does this and which kind of wiring.
Answer is: Container does this and Secondary type of wiring is supported, primitives need to be done manually.

Question: How container know what type of wiring ?

Answer: We define it as byType,byName,constructor.

Question: Is there are way we do not define type of autowiring ?

Answer: Yes, it's there by doing one annotation, @Autowired.

Question: But how system know, I need to pick this type of secondary data ?

Answer: You will provide that data in you spring.xml file or by using sterotype annotations to your class so that container can themselves create the objects for you.

Answer (score 1):

Standard way:

```
@RestController
public class Main {
    UserService userService;

    public Main(){
        userService = new UserServiceImpl();
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return userService.print("Example test");
    }
}
```

User service interface:

```
public interface UserService {
    String print(String text);
}
```

UserServiceImpl class:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Override
    public String print(String text) {
        return text + " UserServiceImpl";
    }
}
```

Output: `Example test UserServiceImpl`

That is a great example of tight coupled classes, bad design example and there will be problem with testing (PowerMockito is also bad).

Now let's take a look at SpringBoot dependency injection, nice example of loose coupling:

Interface remains the same,

Main class:

```
@RestController
public class Main {
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public Main(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return userService.print("Example test");
    }
}
```

ServiceUserImpl class:

```
@Component
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Override
    public String print(String text) {
        return text + " UserServiceImpl";
    }
}
```

Output: `Example test UserServiceImpl`

and now it's easy to write test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MainTest {
    @Mock
    UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void indexTest() {
        when(userService.print("Example test")).thenReturn("Example test UserServiceImpl");

        String result = new Main(userService).index();

        assertEquals(result, "Example test UserServiceImpl");
    }
}
```

I showed `@Autowired` annotation on constructor but it can also be used on setter or field.

Comment: Why create a constructor for main class? and not autowire the declaration?

Answer (score 0):

The whole concept of inversion of control means you are free from a chore to instantiate objects manually and provide all necessary dependencies.
When you annotate class with appropriate annotation (e.g. `@Service`) Spring will automatically instantiate object for you. If you are not familiar with annotations you can also use XML file instead. However, it's not a bad idea to instantiate classes manually (with the `new` keyword) in unit tests when you don't want to load the whole spring context.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you must enable the `@Autowired` annotation by adding element `<context:annotation-config/>` into the spring configuration file. This will register the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which takes care the processing of annotation.

And then you can autowire your service by using the field injection method.

```
public class YourController{

 @Autowired
 private UserService userService; 

}
```

I found this from the post [Spring @autowired annotation](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-core/spring-autowired-annotation.html)