# How does Spring annotation @Autowired work?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I came across an example of `@Autowired`:

```
public class EmpManager {
   @Autowired
   private EmpDao empDao;
}
```

I was curious about how the `empDao` get sets since there are no setter methods and it is private.

Comment: Look at this post

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153546/how-does-autowiring-work-in-spring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Spring @Autowired usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Java allows access controls on a field or method to be turned off (yes, there's a security check to pass first) via the [`AccessibleObject.setAccessible()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) which is part of the reflection framework (both `Field` and `Method` inherit from `AccessibleObject`). Once the field can be discovered and written to, it's pretty trivial to do the rest of it; merely a [Simple Matter Of Programming](http://catb.org/jargon/html/S/SMOP.html).

Comment: In case you hadn't guessed, I'm impressed with how slick the Spring guys have made their code. I know how they do it, but that doesn't change how good it is.

Comment: I've come across code that doesn't get autowired properties injected until I add a public setter method.  What would cause that?

Comment: @Snekse: No idea offhand. Ask it as a full question, _including the exact version of Spring used_ and _the code in question_ and maybe — probably — someone will be able to tell you.

Comment: It's probably due to Java security policy which is set so that it disables access to private fields using reflection.

Comment: if i am getting your answer , just cross checking it.. you mean that - access controls are auto turned off then what is the need of private access specifier in a class if it is @Autowired

Comment: If it's so simple then give an example.

Answer (score 7):

Java allows you to interact with private members of a class via reflection.

Check out [ReflectionTestUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html), which is very handy for writing unit tests.

Answer (score 4):

No need for any setter, you just have to declare the `EmpDao` class with the annotation `@component` in order that Spring identifies it as part of the components which are contained in the ApplicationContext ...

You have 2 solutions:

- To manually declare your beans in the XML file applicationContext :

```
<bean class="package.EmpDao" />
```

- To use automatic detection by seeting these lines in your context file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

**AND** to use the spring annotation to declare the classes that your spring container will manage as components:

```
@Component
class EmpDao {...}
```

**AND** to annotate its reference by `@Autowired`:

```
@Component (or @Controller, or @Service...)
class myClass {

// tells the application context to inject an instance of EmpDao here
@Autowired
EmpDao empDao;


public void useMyDao()
{
    empDao.method();
}
...
}
```

Autowiring happens by placing an instance of one bean into the desired field in an instance of another bean. Both classes should be beans, i.e. they should be defined to live in the application context.

Spring knows the existence of the beans `EmpDao` and `MyClass` and will instantiate automatically an instance of `EmpDao` in `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses the [CGLib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) API to provide autowired dependency injection.

---

### References

- [Usage of CGLib forum comment by Rod Johnson](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=12932#post13735)
- [3.3.1. Injecting dependencies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators)
- [Pro Spring - Analyzing Spring Dependencies](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=q2PIjAJoXsAC&lpg=PA19&ots=PSEpU9C-uM&dq=spring%20di%20cglib&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q=spring%20di%20cglib&f=false)

### Further Reading

- [Introduction to the Spring Framework](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363858/Introduction-to-the-Spring-Framework) by Rod Johnson

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, @Autowired does not require any instrumentation, just reflection.  Other annotations like @Transactional do require instrumentation.

Comment: I agree, @Autowired should not use CGLib. Only factory injection or proxy classes etc.