# @Resource vs @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, autowired

Which annotation, **@Resource** ([jsr250](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=250)) or **@Autowired** (Spring-specific) should I use in DI?

I have successfully used both in the past, `@Resource(name="blah")` and `@Autowired @Qualifier("blah")`

My instinct is to stick with the `@Resource` tag since it's been ratified by the jsr people.
Anyone has strong thoughts on this?

Comment: FYI - I removed the 'update', it should have been asked as a separate question. As per this rejected comment,
"This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner"

Answer (score 213, accepted):

In spring pre-3.0 it doesn't matter which one.

In spring 3.0 there's support for the standard ([JSR-330](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330)) annotation `@javax.inject.Inject` - use it, with a combination of `@Qualifier`. Note that spring now also supports the `@javax.inject.Qualifier` meta-annotation:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface YourQualifier {}
```

So you can have

```
<bean class="com.pkg.SomeBean">
   <qualifier type="YourQualifier"/>
</bean>
```

or

```
@YourQualifier
@Component
public class SomeBean implements Foo { .. }
```

And then:

```
@Inject @YourQualifier private Foo foo;
```

This makes less use of String-names, which can be misspelled and are harder to maintain.

---

As for the original question: both, without specifying any attributes of the annotation, perform injection by type. The difference is:

- `@Resource` allows you to specify a name of the injected bean
- `@Autowired` allows you to mark it as non-mandatory.

Comment: This might see like a silly question, but when you use this style of injection, do you need a public setter for `foo` or a constructor in `SomeBean` with a `Foo` param?

Comment: @Snekse - Got my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536674/how-does-spring-autowired-work

Comment: nope. You don't need any of that. Just the field. (Spring populates it via reflection)

Comment: @Bozho This answer actually does not show the difference between `@Resource` and `@Autowired`, actual answer is the one posted by  @Ichthyo, I think this one must be updated.

Comment: yes. In fact I sometimes answer questions by providing a better alternative to the approach. But I included the answer to the original question below, for completeness

Comment: Note that to use @Inject you need an additional dependency.  Maven artifact and/or jar file download can be found here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.inject%7Cjavax.inject%7C1%7Cjar

Answer (score 585):

Both `@Autowired` (or `@Inject`) and `@Resource` work equally well. But there is a conceptual difference or a difference in the meaning

- `@Resource` means get me a **known resource by name**. The name is extracted from the name of the annotated setter or field, or it is taken from the name-Parameter.
- `@Inject` or `@Autowired` try to wire in a **suitable other component by type**.

These are two quite distinct concepts. Unfortunately, the Spring-Implementation of `@Resource` has a built-in fallback, which kicks in when resolution-by-name fails. In this case, it falls back to the `@Autowired`-kind resolution-by-type. While this fallback is convenient, it causes a lot of confusion, because people are unaware of the conceptual difference and tend to use `@Resource` for type-based autowiring.

Comment: Yes, this is what should be an accepted answer. For example if you have a `@Resource` annotated field, and field name matches the id of a bean in container then Spring will throw  `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException` if their types differ - this is because beans are first matched by name in `@Resource` annotation, not by type. But if name of the property doesn't match the name of the bean, then Spring will wire them by type.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question rather than simply recommending an entirely different "best practice" as the accepted answer does.  I also found this blog post, which shows results of several common scenarios with all three annotation styles, helpful: http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/

Comment: For the reader, please find a summary of the article pointed by @Jules here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23887596/363573

Comment: One implication of this: When you want to inject a Map/List bean, `@Autowire` can't and won't work. You will have to use `@Resource` in that case.

Comment: @autowire will be by type if it is written over a setter method , if its on the reference then it will be by name.

Comment: Since this answer confused me ("... @Resource has a built-in fallback,  which kicks in when resolution by-name fails"), I'd like to point out that when using `@Resource` with a `name`, it will never ignore the name and fallback to inject something that only matches by type (Spring 5).   If you use `@Resource` without specifying a name, then it does indeed inject by type.  I think using `@Resource` without the name parameter should probably be considered bad practice.

Answer (score 87):

The primary difference is, `@Autowired` is a spring annotation. Whereas `@Resource` is specified by the JSR-250, as you pointed out yourself. So the latter is part of Java whereas the former is Spring specific.

Hence, you are right in suggesting that, in a sense. I found folks use `@Autowired` with `@Qualifier` because it is more powerful. Moving from some framework to some other is considered very unlikely, if not myth, especially in the case of Spring.

Comment: +1, because `@Autowired` with `@Qualifier` really _is_ more powerful than the JSR standard `@Resource` annotation (think of optional dependencies for instance with `@Autowired(required=false)`. You can't do that with `@Resource`)

Answer (score 76):

I would like to emphasize one comment from [@Jules](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441899/jules) on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10916767/363573) to this question. The comment brings a useful link: [Spring Injection with @Resource, @Autowired and @Inject](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/). I encourage you to read it entirely, however here is a quick summary of its usefulness:

#### How annotations select the right implementation?

`@Autowired` and `@Inject`

1. Matches by Type
2. Restricts by Qualifiers
3. Matches by Name

`@Resource`

1. Matches by Name
2. Matches by Type
3. Restricts by Qualifiers (ignored if match is found by name)

#### Which annotations (or combination of) should I use for injecting my beans?

1. Explicitly name your component [@Component("beanName")]
2. Use `@Resource` with the `name` attribute [@Resource(name="beanName")]

#### Why should I not use `@Qualifier`?

Avoid `@Qualifier` annotations unless you want to create a list of similar beans. For example you may want to mark a set of rules with a specific `@Qualifier` annotation. This approach makes it simple to inject a group of rule classes into a list that can be used for processing data.

#### Does bean injection slow my program?

Scan specific packages for components `[context:component-scan base-package="com.sourceallies.person"]`. While this will result in more `component-scan` configurations it reduces the chance that you’ll add unnecessary components to your Spring context.

---

***Reference:*** [Spring Injection with @Resource, @Autowired and @Inject](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/)

Answer (score 40):

This is what I got from the [Spring 3.0.x Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/ch03s09.html) :-

> Tip
>
> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do
>   not primarily use @Autowired, even if is technically capable of
>   referring to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, use the
>   JSR-250 @Resource annotation, which is semantically defined to
>   identify a specific target component by its unique name, with the
>   declared type being irrelevant for the matching process.
>
> As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, beans that are
>   themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected
>   through @Autowired, because type matching is not properly applicable
>   to them. Use @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific
>   collection or map bean by unique name.
>
> @Autowired applies to fields, constructors, and multi-argument
>   methods, allowing for narrowing through qualifier annotations at the
>   parameter level. By contrast, @Resource is supported only for fields
>   and bean property setter methods with a single argument. As a
>   consequence, stick with qualifiers if your injection target is a
>   constructor or a multi-argument method.

Comment: For the current version see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers (the tip was updated)

Answer (score 30):

@Autowired + @Qualifier will work only with spring DI, if you want to use some other DI in future @Resource is good option.

other difference which I found very significant is @Qualifier does not support dynamic bean wiring, as @Qualifier does not support placeholder, while @Resource does it very well.

For example:
if you have an interface with multiple implementations like this

```
interface parent {

}
@Service("actualService")
class ActualService implements parent{

}
@Service("stubbedService")
class SubbedService implements parent{

}
```

with @Autowired & @Qualifier you need to set specific child implementation 
like

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("actualService") or 
@Qualifier("stubbedService") 
Parent object;
```

which does not provide placeholder while with @Resource you can put placeholder and use property file to inject specific child implementation like

```
@Resource(name="${service.name}")
Parent object;
```

where service.name is set in property file as

```
#service.name=actualService
 service.name=stubbedService
```

Hope that helps someone :)

Answer (score 19):

Both of them are equally good. The advantage of using Resource is in future if you want to another DI framework other than spring, your code changes will be much simpler. Using Autowired your code is tightly coupled with springs DI.

Comment: Never gonna happen. And even if it did - doing a find/replace on annotation names is going to be the least of your problems.

Answer (score 19):

When you analyze critically from the base classes of these two annotations.You will realize the following differences.

`@Autowired` uses `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`  to inject dependencies.
`@Resource` uses `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to inject dependencies.

Even though they use different post processor classes they all behave nearly identically.
The differences critically lie in their execution paths, which I have highlighted below.

```
@Autowired / @Inject
```

1.Matches by Type
2.Restricts by Qualifiers
3.Matches by Name

```
@Resource
```

1.Matches by Name
2.Matches by Type
3.Restricts by Qualifiers (ignored if match is found by name)

Answer (score 6):

With `@Resource` you can do bean self-injection, it might be needed in order to run all extra logic added by bean post processors like transactional or security related stuff.

With Spring 4.3+ `@Autowired` is also capable of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

`@Resource` is often used by high-level objects, defined via JNDI. `@Autowired` or `@Inject` will be used by more common beans.

As far as I know, it's not a specification, nor even a convention. It's more the logical way standard code will use these annotations.

Answer (score 0):

As a note here:
`SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext` and `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext` **DOES NOT** work with `@Resource`  annotation. So, there are difference.