# Mock get accessor in kotlin with mockito 3

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I want to mock a variable with mockito3 and I have mockito-inline enabled but when I run the test it calls the real get accessor and it ignores my mock.

```
Mockito.`when`(mock.myVal).thenReturn(false)
```

and I got

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: what is the data type of the value ?

Comment: @YQadoome It's boolean

Comment: i guess you have the same problem :https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995712/7373745

Comment: @YQadoome yes that's right. thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking member variables of a class using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995540/mocking-member-variables-of-a-class-using-mockito)