# Difference between @Qualifier and @Resource

Tags: java, spring

I don’t see any difference between two ways, *@Qualifier* is always used with *@Autowired*.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("alpha")
```

VS

```
@Resource(name="alpha")
```

Anyone could let me know the difference? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [@Resource vs @Autowired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`@Autowired` can be used alone . If it is used alone , it will be wired by type . So problems arises if  more than one bean of the same type are declared in the container as `@Autowired` does not know which beans to use to inject. As a result , use `@Qualifier` together with `@Autowired` to clarify which beans to be actually wired by specifying the bean name (wired by name)

`@Resource` is wired by name too . So if `@Autowired` is used together with `@Qualifier` , it is the same as the `@Resource`.

The difference are that `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier` are the spring annotation while `@Resource` is the standard java annotation (from JSR-250) . Besides , `@Resource`  only supports for fields and setter injection while  `@Autowired` supports fields , setter ,constructors and multi-argument methods injection.

It is suggested to use `@Resource` for fields and setter injection. Stick with `@Qualifier` and `@Autowired` for constructor or a multi-argument method injection.

See [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers):

> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not
>   primarily use @Autowired - even if is technically capable of referring
>   to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, prefer the JSR-250
>   @Resource annotation which is semantically defined to identify a
>   specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type
>   being irrelevant for the matching process.

Comment: Where does it actually say that? I see that it says to use it if you want to autowire by name, I don't see where it's recommended that resource is preferred (and it won't actually work under some circumstances).

Comment: Updated  .It is said in the Tips section in the  3.11.3

Answer (score 5):

I was facing some issues with @Autowired and then started using @Qualifier and I was finally able to find out the when to use @Autowired with @Qualifier when multiple beans of same type are defined.

Suppose you define 2 beans of same type but different values :

```
<bean id="appContext1" class="com.context.AppContext">
     <constructor-arg value="abc" />
<bean/>
<bean id="appContext2" class="com.context.AppContext">
     <constructor-arg value="ABC" />
<bean/>
```

Then if you just are trying to use @Autowire, then you have to use the same variable name as of the bean name else it will give error as multiple types found.

```
@Autowired
AppContext appContext;
```

For the above use case you have to use Qualifier.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("appContext1")
AppContext appContext;
```

Instead, if you use the variable name same as bean name, you can eliminate the use of @Qualifier.

```
@Autowired
AppContext appContext1;
```

I was always using the variable name same as bean name, but accidentally had some other variable name and faced this issue.

Let me know if there are any doubts.

Answer (score 3):

@Autowired is old school Spring.  @Resource is the Java EE CDI standard.  Spring handles both (as well as @Inject, which is very similar) and does pretty much the same thing in both situations.  I would recommend @Resource, @Autowired was made prior to the standard and seems to be supported mostly for backward compatibility.

Comment: so u mean @ Resource is current spring standard . we should use @ Resource rather than @ Autowired in our Spring beans