# Spring dependencies not injected for Cucumber runner

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I have existing test cases which use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner which use @Resource annotation to flag variable for injection.

@Resource is used as another DI framework may be used in the future.
([@Resource vs @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired))

Now I have started writing BDD test cases using the Cucumber runner. However DI does not appear to be happening. (@Autowired works but not @Resource) Anyone know why not?

Comment: According to the link `Resource vs Autowired` they both are not recommended since spring 3.0 - so consider to move on to `interface Inject` annotation from JSR-330.

Answer (score 5):

(I'm assuming you're using Cucumber-JVM)

Instead of using **SpringJUnit4ClassRunner**, you should use the **Cucumber** runner instead.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
```

To use this you will need the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${info.cukes.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${info.cukes.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${info.cukes.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This will look for **cucumber.xml** in your class path. This XML is simply a spring bean configuration XML. Mine is pretty straight forward and contains:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="cucumber.runtime.java.spring"/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- wire beans required for testing -->
<import resource="classpath*:/context.xml"/>
```

When you run your tests you should see Spring load **cucumber.xml** and then import **context.xml**.