# Get bean of @Service annotated class?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

In my web application, I am not using `applicationContext.xml`. How can I get the bean of `@Service` annotated class?

If I used the `applicationContext.xml` in my web application, I have to load the `applicationContext.xml` every time to get the bean of the `@Service` annotated class.

I used this way

```
WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext);
ServerConnection  con = (ServerConnection ) ctx.getBean("con");
```

My Service class will be as ,

```
@Service  or @Service("con")
public class ServerConnection {

    private  TServerProtocol tServerProtocol;
    private  URI uri;

    public TServerProtocol getServerConnection(){

        System.out.println("host :"+host+"\nport :"+port);

        try {
            uri = new URI("tcp://" + host + ":" + port);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in xreating URI Path");
        }

        tServerProtocol = new TServerProtocol(new Endpoint(uri));
        return tServerProtocol;
    }
}
```

Is there *any other way to get a bean* of this class ?

or

What is the proper way to get a bean of `@Service` annotated class in case of core application and web application in Spring3.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using annotation-based configuration, you use `@Autowired` to get the bean by its type or `@Resource` to get the bean by its name. Use only one of these for any particular property (to keep confusion down).

```
@Autowired
private ServerConnection connection;
```

```
@Resource(name = "con")
private ServerConnection connection;
```

[There's also `@Inject`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095239/301832), but I don't like that as it gets less nice as the number of beans goes up. YMMV.

Answer (score 6):

`ApplicationContext context=SpringApplication.run(YourProjectApplication.class, args);`

this context can be used to get the beans created by annotation `@Bean` and `@Service`
as

`context.getBean(className.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making use of annotation, I believe you would prefer the use of **@Autowired**. If you have a class that will call `ServerConnection` (lets say `CallingClass` under package `com.foo`), then this is how it would look like:

```
package com.foo;

@Component
public class CallingClass{

   @Autowired
   private ServerConnection serverConnection

    // add your getters and setters
}
```

Then on your applicationContext.xml just add the following

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo" />
```

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: I used this already. My question is how to get the instance of this class apart from this way.

Comment: Apart from this and what you have mentioned above, I believe there's no other way, that is if you want to leverage Spring's DI.

Answer (score 0):

If you working in some bean outside spring then you can use normal Spring annotations:

```
@Autowired
private Dependency1 dependency1;

@Autowired
private Dependency2 dependency2;

@Autowired
private Dependency2 dependency2;
```

then call one time from inside of this class:

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```

to inject all dependencies. It may be more convinient if you have multiple dependencies.

Comment: hi Maaksym, i tried using SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); but it does inject the beans which are described in applicationContext.xml file but not the annoted beans.

Comment: @Amit Sharma please post your problem as a separate question