# Spring (autowired) component use multiple in the same class

Tags: java, spring

I have been started use Spring recently. And I didn't find the solution to my problem.

I have a component:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Log4j2
public class CompX { ....
```

I would like to use it twice in a (component) class:

```
...
@Autowired
private CompX current;

@Autowired
private CompX old;
...
```

How can I do this?
Always got following exception.

> "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type..."

Comment: user Qualifier annotation.. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Required Multiple beans of same type in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711924/required-multiple-beans-of-same-type-in-spring)

Comment: Do you declare a CompX bean in a Spring `.xml` file ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because ambiguity and spring is confused which one to consider so please tell spring which one to use by qualifying like below :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("current")
private CompX current;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("old")
private CompX old;
```