# How to put a RestTemplate into a separate class?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have a Spring application with the following definition of `RestTemplate`:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.mycompany"})
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

[...]
  @Bean
  public RestTemplate getRestTemplate1() {
    return new RestTemplate();
  }

  @Bean("restTemplate2")
  public RestTemplate getRestTemplate2() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    [...]
  }

[...]

}
```

I want to put `getRestTemplate2` into a separate class. So I created the following class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class GetRestTemplate2 {
    @Bean("restTemplate2")
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate2() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
      [...]
    }

}
```

When I start the application I get the error message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'restTemplate2' 
defined in class path resource [XXXXXXXX.class]: Cannot register bean definition 
[Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; 
factoryBeanName=restTemplate2; factoryMethodName=getRestTemplate2; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined 
in class path resource [XXXXXXXXX.class]] for bean 'restTemplate2': 
There is already [Generic bean: class [XXXXXXXXX]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; 
lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; 
initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file 
[XXXXXXXX.class]] bound.
```

How can I make sure that the code creating `restTemplate2` is located in a separate class and properly detected by Spring?

**Update 1:** Renaming `GetRestTemplate2` class to `GetRestTemplate2Config` did not help.

Comment: Just a sanity check, did you remove the bean definition from the MyApplication.java file?

Comment: @Michal I removed the second one, i. e. in `MyApplication` there is now only `getRestTemplate1`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711924/required-multiple-beans-of-same-type-in-spring

Comment: @4EACH What part of the answer is supposed to help with my question? I don't see any beans in separate classes there.

Comment: the last answer looks relevant to you @Mentiflectax

Comment: Whatever `XXXXXXXXX` is, that already has this bean definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class GetRestTemplate2Config {

    @Bean(name = "restTemplate2")
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate2() throws KeyStoreException, 
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
       [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need the `@ComponentScan` annotation on your configuration class, unless `GetRestTemplate2 ` is in a completely different (non-nested) package structure.