# Idea inspects batis mapper bean wrong

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, mybatis, inspection

There's web project with Spring and MyBatis. I use IntelliJ IDEA for development. 
IDEA cannot correctly inspect MyBatis beans and produces annoying underscorings, though link to Data Access Object is present.

Inspection comment:

```
 Could not autowire. No beans of 'ApplicationMapper' type found.
```

My Spring and MyBatis configurations:
Spring:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:spring/mybatis-config.xml"/>

</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.db.gbs.gbsapps.rds.backend.model.integration.mapping"/>
</bean>
```

mybatis-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="mybatis/ApplicationMapper.xml"/>
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Is there a way to fix this small issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated MyBatis plugin is fixed and does not have this issue.

Comment: update to which version? My baits plugin has not updated automaticly so I guess its latest.

Answer (score 19):

```
@Repository
@Mapper 
public interface ApplicationMapper {
```

will do the trick

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to add `@Component` or `@Repository` to your mapper interface.

Such as:

```
@Repository
public interface ApplicationMapper {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem.
In my Intelli J Inspection Error,

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'ApplicationMapper' type found. less... (Ctrl+F1)
>   Checks autowiring problems in a bean class.

in my case, disabled inspections. (Alt + Enter quick fix or change settings)

> Settings - Editor - Inspections - Spring - Spring Core - Code - Autowiring for Bean Class - disable

(2015.04.27 update) After installed myBatis plugin, I had solved this problem, too

Comment: These inspection is very useful, so disabling is not the way. Actually, updated MyBatis plugin is fixed and does not have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After installed myBatis plugin, I had solved this problem, too.

Answer (score 2):

How about defining a new annotation for convenience:

```
@Repository
@Mapper
public @interface MyMapper{

}

@MyMapper
public interface ApplicationMapper {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, myBatis plugin dose not work. Adding the following before the variable declaration will work.

```
@Autowired
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
private ApplicationMapper applicationMapper;@Autowired
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Resource
UserMapper userMapper;
```

Other related thing : [resource vs autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired)