# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException while trying to use the @Autowired annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am creating an application which uses Controller, Service and Dao classes.Service and Dao are created as interface which are implemented using their implementation classes. I have a controller class named UserGroupController and its service as UserGroupService. .The code snippet would be:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("module/usergroup")
public class UserGroupController 
{
    @Autowired
    UserGroupService userGroupService;
```

This @AutoWired annotation is causing the issue and when I remove just that annotation, everything works without exception.But if I do not use that annotation, whenever I try to access any method my service class, I am getting a null pointer exception.

My Service class is like shown below:

```
@Repository("userGroupService")
public interface UserGroupService
```

and its implementation is:

```
public class UserGroupServiceImpl implements UserGroupService
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "userGroupDao")
    UserGroupDao userGroupDao;
```

And the exception is:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userGroupController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.smartwcm.core.user.service.UserGroupService com.smartwcm.admin.user.controller.UserGroupController.userGroupService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.smartwcm.core.user.service.UserGroupService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.smartwcm.core.user.service.UserGroupService com.smartwcm.admin.user.controller.UserGroupController.userGroupService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.smartwcm.core.user.service.UserGroupService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.smartwcm.core.user.service.UserGroupService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: ok.... so what is the BeanCreationException you are getting? Without that, we can't really help. And if you remove @Autowired, then your userGroupService will be null, because nothing will be injected into it

Comment: The exception message is extremely clear: There's no bean available that matches what you're requesting for injection. Figure out why that bean isn't included.

Comment: You shoud anotate your UserGroupServiceImpl

Comment: You also shouldn't need to qualify any of your `@Service` or `@Repository` annotations with anything after them. As long as they are being picked up by classpath scanning, they are eligible to be autowired by type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be following the standard Repository, Service, Controller pattern.

**@Controller** : Controller annotation is used to denote that the class is controller. It contains method which serve the http requests, request mappings are done at method level or class level.  
**@Service** : Annotate all your service classes with @Service. All your business logic will be in Service classes. Controller and DAO layers will not have any business logic in there.  
**@Repository** : Annotate all your DAO classes with @Repository. All your database access logic should be in DAO classes.

So in your case, annotations should be:

```
@Repository("userGroupDao")
public class UserGroupDaoImpl implements UserGroupDao

@Service("userGroupService")
public class UserGroupServiceImpl implements UserGroupService

@Controller
public class UserGroupController
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the solution I was looking for....The solution worked for my application and was educative too

Answer (score 0):

Why annotate it with `@Repository`? you can use that for your DAO classes.

(1) Annotate with **`@Service`** instead

```
@Service
public interface UserGroupService
```

(2) Or you can define your UserGroupService as a bean in your Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="userGroupService" class="com.your.package.UsergroupService" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you move the `@Repository` annotation to the implementation class. Please find below the sample code:

**Interface class:**

```
public interface Test {
    public void printMessage(String msg);
}
```

**Implementation class:**

```
@Repository("testService")
public class TestImpl implements Test {

    @Override
    public void printMessage(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
    }

}
```

**Configuration class:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.praxissummit.eperf.api.domain.test")
public class TestConfig {

}
```

**Main class:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = 
           new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestConfig.class);
        ctx.getBean("testService", Test.class).printMessage("Hello world!!");
    }
}
```

If I move the `@Repository` annotation to the interface, spring throws `No bean named 'testService' is defined`

**Note:** You should actually annotate your service class with `@Service`, not `@Repository`

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` is confusing sometimes. You can use more general java `@Resource (jsr250)` annotation. `@Resource` means get me a known resource by name. The name is extracted from the name of the annotated setter or field, or it is taken from the name-Parameter. `@Resource` has a built-in fallback, which kicks in when resolution by-name fails. In this case, it falls back to the `@Autowired`-kind resolution by-type.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("module/usergroup")
public class UserGroupController 
{
    @Resource(name="UserGroupService")
    UserGroupService userGroupService;
```

and for your service you can choose from `@Component` or `@Service`

```
@Service
public interface UserGroupService { }
```

Hope it will sort out your problem. Check out the difference between `@Autowired` and `@Resource` for more clarity. [@Resource vs @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired)

`@Service` or `@Component` annotation is used for spring container, it will create the object on the fly. You can even opt out the above annotation if you are using `@Resource`(provided you use `@Resource` every where for your service class)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `@Service` annotation to your service class implementation, so that it can be picked up by classpath scanning, added to the Spring context and then be eligible to be Autowired.

```
package com.foo.bar.service;

@Service
public class UserGroupServiceImpl implements UserGroupService
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "userGroupDao")
    UserGroupDao userGroupDao;
```

Also ensure that if your service class is in package `com.foo.bar.service`, that you have that package included in the component scan package tag in your XML. Example:

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar" />
```