# How to use @Inject annotation properly in spring Java based configuration?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am new to the spring and got stuck on some point as explained below -

I have a class color with two different implementation name as Red and Blue and I would like to inject both into the List of  color using `@inject`.

```
Below is my ApplicationConfiguration class 

package org.arpit.java2blog.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.arpit.java2blog.model.Country;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@Import(CountryConfig.class)
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Inject
    private List<Color> colorList;

    @Bean
    public List<Color> colorList() {
        System.out.println("Second");
        List<Color> aList = new ArrayList<Color>();
        aList.add(new Blue());
        return aList;
    }

}
```

but getting exception as

> Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private java.util.List
>   org.arpit.java2blog.config.ApplicationConfiguration.colorList; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [org.arpit.java2blog.config.Color] found for
>   dependency [collection of org.arpit.java2blog.config.Color]: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this
>   dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}

Comment: How does you class `Color` look like? Does it have `@Component` annotation? is it available in Spring context?

Comment: No it's just a simple plain class with no @component

Comment: not sure but the same thing is working fine with @resource annotation

Comment: How does your color class look like? If it's unknown to the spring context it can't be autowired.

Comment: public interface Color {} have two implementation Red and Blue both are plain class with no annotation but Not sure how it is working fine with @resource annotation

Comment: Never used resource annotation. Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to populate your `colorList` using `@Inject` is shown in the below code with inline comments:

```
@Configuration
@Import(CountryConfig.class)
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Inject
    private List<Color> colorList;

    @Bean
    public Color color() {
      return new Blue();//injects Blue object to colorList
    }

    @Bean
    public Color color() {
      return new Red();//injects Red object to colorList
    }
}
```

Also, you can very well use `@Order` to inject `Color` object at a specific index of `colorList` inside as explained in the Spring doc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation).

> The solution is working fine, if I remove @component annotation from both the classes
>   red and blue and only provide one bean type after removing component

When you mark your bean classes with `@Component` (infact for any Spring stereotype annotations), the beans will become eligible for injection and will be automatically loaded into your `colorList`. So when you provide `@Bean` annotation method and giving one more object then that also will be added to the list, but in general, you will load the list either using `@Component` or using `@Bean`, but not both.