# Is an empty entry in configuration loaded as null for a Resource Map in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

If I have a configuration file (`yml` or `properties`) and I have a blank entry like the one below:

```
some.entry =
```

When I load that entry as a `@Resource` of a given bean, like this:

```
@Resource(name = "someEntry")
Map<String, List<String>> someMap;
```

Will the `someMap` end up as `null` or an empty Map?

And would the behavior be different if instead of `@Resource` a similar approach with `@Value` is used?

Comment: `@Resource` seems to require an existing bean which can ge injected. If no such bean is defined it throws a `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. Info from [this website](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire). Sadly they don't tell what happens if you use a file whith only the identifier. I would assume that it becomes `null` as you don't define anything but the name

Comment: it's been answered in this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired)

Comment: @davidhan I can't seem to find where they answer what the value of the variable becomes after loading for this scenario, independently of Resource,Autowired, etc.
Where did you see that info?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I assume that too, but I wanted to be sure if it either becomes `null` or it becomes an empty Map.

Comment: You could simply test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `@Resource` and `@Value` will convert `some.entry =` to `null`.

Comment: Can you kindly provide some example code (on Github for example) that we can clone and see this happening?