# Ignore JNDI-Resource injection (@Resource) in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jndi

I am currently experimenting with Spring Boot and I'm trying to include a library class which is currently used in a Java EE context.
Said class has a parent class which has a `@Resource` injection with a JNDI lookup name.

In a reduced example, the involved classes look like this:

*Configuration.java*

```java
@Configuration
public class Facades {
  @Bean
  public Connection connection() {
    return new Connection();
  }

  @Bean
  public Facade facade(Connection connection) {
    return new Facade(connection);
  }
}
```

*Facade + ParentFacade*

```java
public class ParentFacade {
  @Resource(lookup = "eis/Connection")  // <-- the problem
  protected Connection connection;
}

public class Facade extends ParentFacade {
  public Facade(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
  }
}
```

When I run the application, following error appears:

> Invalid bean definition with name '**eis/Connection**' defined in JNDI
>   environment: **JNDI lookup failed**; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: **Need to specify class name in
>   environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an
>   application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial**

Obviously, I don't need the `@Resource` injection since I can inject the connection by constructor.
However, Spring always attempts to inject a bean with the JNDI name dynamically.

I have tried to exclude the class from IoC inclusion with following annotations, but it made no difference:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = "the.package",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                classes = { Facade.class, ParentFacade.class }
        )
)
```

My question now is:
Can I either

- make Spring ignore the `@Resource` annotation in the problematic class OR
- inject a `@Bean` with the required JNDI-name (*eis/Connection*)?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.:
changing the library class which contains the `@Resource` annotation is not an option

Comment: Where are you setting up your JNDI InitialContext?  What does that look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need @Resource(name = "connection")

Comment: That doesn't work - this would work if the `@Resource` annotation would use 'name' and not 'lookup' as a parameter.

Comment: @Resource uses `name` also. Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired ?

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the library class, which contains the `@Resource` annotation is not an option. This means that I cannot simply change _lookup_ to _name_.
My goal is either to completely ignore the `@Resource` annotation or to inject it otherwise.