# how is @Resorce different from @AutoWired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

can it be used interchangeably?

documentation is not clear.

is it it one can be used with xml and other with spring boot?

eg

```
@Resource
private User user;

@Autowired
private User user
```

when to use each ad when to avoid these ?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired