# why there is no corresponding set method in this case?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I am new to Spring and working on a project which is consisting of Spring in it .
It has got this piece of code inside the xml file

```
   <bean id="quotClient" class="com..at.client.QuoteClient" scope="singleton" />
   <bean id="streamClient" class="com.at.client.StreamClient" scope="singleton" />
```

And inside the java class it has got this piece of code

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("streamClient")
private StreamClient sclient;



@Autowired
@Qualifier("quotClient")
private QuoteClient quotesClient;


public void setQuotesClient(QuoteClient quotesClient) {
    this.quotesClient = quotesClient;
}
```

Please let me know why there is no method by name set for the StreamClient class , but which has got corresponding set method for QuoteClient  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using annotation driven Autowiring of the beans you don't need any setters for injunction (these are set by using reflection). Even `setQuotesClient` isn't needed by Spring DI framework to inject those 2 bean instances.

PS: From spring version 3.0, you can start using `@Inject` instead of `@Autowired`.

[**Check: How does Spring @Autowired work**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536674/how-does-spring-autowired-work)

Answer (score 0):

i think that setter method wrote by mistake.
remove that setter and test the application. it should work.