# Which type of Dependency Injection it is when we have @Autowire on a class field?

Tags: java, spring

One way is the DI using `setter` methods. Other way is using `constructor`.

I am just curious to know which type of DI the following way is :

```
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    TestService service;
    ...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=field+injection

Answer (score 2):

That is "field injection". Generally you can choose from 3 types:

- Field injection
- Constructor injection
- Setter injection

Each of them has advantages and disadvantages. During the testing field injection is normal practice.

Answer (score 1):

In case of @Autowiring in a class like:

```
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    TestService service;
    ...
}
```

Autowire your object on using reflection, hence no need for Setter methods

Check this post: [How does Spring @Autowired work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536674/how-does-spring-autowired-work)