# Do we have to write setter method to use @Inject annotation?

Tags: java, spring, inject, spring-framework-beans

is it mandatory to write a setter function when we use @Inject annotation

Comment: the documentation of that annotation explains what it can do: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Inject.html

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It is not mandatory. Reflection is used to set the value.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536674/how-does-spring-annotation-autowired-work) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142622/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-autowired-in-spring-framework-which) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

No, we don,t have to write the setter method for @Inject, it is same annotation as the @Autowired.

@Inject is part of a Java technology called CDI that defines a standard for dependency injection similar to Spring. In a Spring application, the two annotations works the same way as Spring has decided to support some JSR-299 annotations in addition to their own.

@Inject can be injected the reference to the implementation of the Provider interface, which allows injecting the deferred references.