# Spring MVC - How does @Autowired work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I am working on a web application using Java and Spring. I'm new at Spring, so as an opportunity to learn, I was basically given an existing application and was told to extend it.
I am having trouble understanding how the @Autowired work. I understand the high-level concept of dependency injection, but I want to know how the @Autowired annotation knows which concrete implementation of an interface to inject?

To put my question into context, I will explain the problem I am having:

> I have an *interface* called **PostDao**, and a *class* called **PostDaoImpl** which implements **PostDao**. I then have another *class* called **PostDaoPublicImpl** which extends **PostDaoImpl**. These classes exist in my persistence layer.
>
> I then have an *interface* called **PostService**, and a *class* called called **PostServiceImpl** which implement **PostService**. I then have another *class* called **PostServicePublicImpl** which extends **PostServiceImpl**. These classes exist in my services layer.

In **PostServiceImpl** the following line injects the following object:

```
@Autowired private PostDao postDao; 
//This injects an object of the class PostDaoImpl
```

My problem is, in **PostServicePublicImpl** how do I have the same declaration as above, but have it inject an object of the class **PostDaoPublicImpl**:

```
@Autowired private PostDao postDao; 
//This injects an object of the class PostDaoPublicImpl
```

I feel as though if I understand how the @Autowired annotation works, then I will be able to solve this problem. Any help and suggestions to solve the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to [understand how Autowiring works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153546/how-does-autowiring-work-in-spring)

then in the bean definition, define **autowire strategy** - let it be **byName** for our case

```
<bean id="postDaoPublicImpl" class="com.yourpackage.PostDaoPublicImpl" autowire="byName" />
```

that means, if any class has a property with name "postDaoPublicImpl", which is the bean id of above bean, will be automatically injected with the bean instance

after that in your class `PostServicePublicImpl` define property like this

```
class PostServicePublicImpl  {

@Autowired private PostDaoPublicImpl postDaoPublicImpl; 
//here Spring will auto inject PostDaoPublicImpl implementation, since this property name matches the bean id and (auto wiring strategy is "byName")

}
```

Comment: i get a runtime error: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private xx.persistence.dao.PostDao xx.services.impl.PostServiceImpl.postDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [xx.persistence.dao.PostDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [postDaoImpl, postDaoPublicImpl]

Comment: in bean definition you have defined 2 beans which can be cast to `za.co.entelect.projects.codereview.persistence.dao.PostDao`, which is creating confusion. Fist set autowire strategy as byName, and then give different bean id's to those 2 beans

Comment: sanbhat could you please edit the package stated in your comment to format i used in my edited comment

Comment: I don't understand why it is telling me that I have defined 2 beans which can be cast to xx.persistance.dao.PostDao. I just added one bean to the application-context.xml file of the Persistance layer.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier solution to my problem. Using the @Qualifier tag I can give a unique name to each implementation of the interface. Then when auto-wiring the object, I just provide a qualifier and the object of the implementation matching the qualifier is injected.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your applicationContext

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```