# 'Class doesn't contain matching constructor for autowiring' error when using Lombok generated contructor

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, lombok

My class has the following annotations:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Autowired)
```

IntelliJ marks the class with the following error (not warning):
"Class doesn't contain matching constructor for autowiring"

Regardless of the error the code compiles and runs without the problem.

I found out that the similar issue (although not with Lombok generated contructors) was an [IntelliJ bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813338/class-doesnt-contain-matching-constructor-for-autowiring), but it's been fixed few years ago.

Based on the above I believe it's an IntelliJ issue as well (I'm using 2019.3.4 Ultimate version).

Any idea what can be done to stop this error from occurring?

Comment: Might not solve your problem, but you don't need the onConstructor argument anymore. @autowired is no longer needed on constructor params in recent versions of spring 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation

Comment: @Andrew Wilkinson That's true if you have only one constructor in class. However in my case I need these two constructors.

Comment: Try version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download If issue remains file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project if possible.

Comment: The [IDEA-175127](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175127) issue looks related.

Comment: The underscore does not seem right according to the api https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/RequiredArgsConstructor.html

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Why exactly? It's described there in the JDK8 part.

Comment: must have not gotten my morning coffee when i wrote that comment

Comment: @Andrey No change on the newest available Idea version with the newest Lombok plugin. I'll try to create some sample code. If I'll be able to reproduce it there (which I expect will happen) I'll file a bug.