# Spring Boot @Autowired

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

I am always facing issues with @Autowired . please any one can share detailed in depth knowledge on @Autowired annotation. with examples will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3153617/4423636

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Spring @Autowired usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414734/understanding-spring-autowired-usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      public class ArticleController {
      @Autowired
      private IArticleService articleService
      }
```

Autowiring is the implcit way to inject dependencies with autowiring no-need to collobrate with property tags and constructor-args tags using xml configuration
In above example instance of IArticleService to the controller.We don't need to explicitly inject through setters or constructors