# Using decorators in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, decorator

I'm a new developper in Node.js (coming from Python), and I'm quite surprised to see that **there are no decorators in Javascript**. I would like to use it, however, because it greatly simplifies the code.

After some research, I found an ES6 specification in stage 2 for this (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators), but it is apparently not supported in Node.js. I also found this in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html), but their function is limited (only in classes).

So my question is: **Is there a way to have decorators similar to those of Python with Node.js, and if not, what features can be used as a substitute ?**

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: Might be better to explain what you want to do that you think is simpler with decorators. Someone might be able to explain how to do it in JavaScript

Comment: I come from java and I was looking decorators for dependency injection. As @sami said, what is your requirement? Also you can check this https://github.com/jrichardsz/dependency-injection-4nodejs

Comment: @JRichardsz what's the benefit of your "injection" over `module.exports = express => { express.get(/*...*/) /*...*/ }` ?

Comment: I need decorators to check args of an function before its execution. I think their syntax is very great for doing that. @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: #JonasWilms benefit is that you don't need to pass express explicitly to another javascript modules, you just need to use it because the **dependency injection core** must instantiate it at the beginning of your app. If you can, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3153617/3957754 and this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrichardsz/static_resources/master/dependency-injection/dependency-injection.png

Comment: Just for your information: https://node.green/ ... great side for learning what's available in Node.js ... for decorators, nothing's available yet: https://node.green/#ESNEXT-Stage-2-Class-and-Property-Decorators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators) decorators in python are just syntactic sugar for a function call, which takes the original class/function and stores the returned value under the variable containing the class. Thus the equivalent js would be:

```
  const Decorated = decorator(class ToBeDecorated {
     /*...*/
  });

  const decoratedFunction = decorateFunction(function decorated() {
     /*...*/
  });

  // Some sample decorator implementations:
  const decorator = Parent => class WithDuck extends Parent {
   quack() { }
  };

  const decorateFunction = fn => (...args) => {
     console.log(`${fn.name} called with`, ...args);
     return fn(...args);
  };
```

Comment: Is it possible to directly call a function decorated with this system ?

Comment: @baptiste0928 `decoratedFunction()` ?

Answer (score 0):

@jonas Wilms 's answer is correct. I wanted to post this here to expand on a specific implementation technique I used. My use case was with Koa, using async/await functions.

First, I created my decorator:

```
export function Cocoon( { param=[] }, callback )
{
    //Return a function from the decorator
    return async (ctx) => {
        //Do a thing with Param
        const params = { usr: param }

        return await callback( ctx, params )
    }
}
```

Using the decorator to annotate a function:

```
export const list = Cocoon({ 
        param: [5]
    },
    async (ctx, { usr }) => {
        //Function body
        ctx.response.body = usr
    }
)
```

Now I can export 'list' to Koa and it'll be called as expected.