# How does Spring know where to search for Components or Beans?

Tags: spring-boot

In an interview i was asked by the interviewer that "***How does Spring know where to search for Components or Beans?***".

As I was not aware about the internal flow details I was not able to answer the question properly.

I said through `@Component` and `@Bean` we can find. But the interviewer was not happy with the question. 
If anybody knows please share your knowledge. TIA

Comment: You search how to `@Autowired` work and you can find your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153546/how-does-autowiring-work-in-spring

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I love to nswer interview questions. Read below...

```
@ComponentScan
```

If you understand Component Scan, you understand Spring.

Spring is a dependency injection framework. It is all about beans and wiring in dependencies.

The first step of defining Spring Beans is by adding the right annotation — `@Component` or `@Service` or `@Repository`.

However, Spring does not know about the bean unless it knows where to search for it.

> **This part of “telling Spring where to search” is called a Component Scan.**

You define the packages that have to be scanned.

Once you define a Component Scan for a package, Spring would search the package and all its sub packages for components/beans.

**Defining a Component Scan**

- If you are using Spring Boot, check the configuration in Approach 1.
- If you are doing a JSP/Servlet or a Spring MVC application without
  using Spring Boot, use Approach 2.

**Approach 1: Component Scan in a Spring Boot Project**

If your other package hierarchies are below your main app with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, you’re covered by the implicit Component Scan.
If there are beans/components in other packages that are not sub-packages of the main package, you should manually add them as `@ComponentScan`

Consider below class

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot.basics.springbootin10steps;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootIn10StepsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext =
            SpringApplication.run(SpringbootIn10StepsApplication.class, args);
        for (String name: applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

`@SpringBootApplication` is defined in the `SpringbootIn10StepsApplication` class which is in the package `com.in28minutes.springboot.basics.springbootin10steps`

`@SpringBootApplication` defines an automatic Component Scan on the package `com.in28minutes.springboot.basics.springbootin10steps`.

You are fine if all your components are defined in the above package or a sub-package of it.

However, let’s say one of the components is defined in package `com.in28minutes.springboot.somethingelse`

In this case, you would need to add the new package into Component Scan.

You have two options:

**Option 1:**

```
@ComponentScan(“com.in28minutes.springboot”)
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootIn10StepsApplication {...}
```

**Option 2:**: Define as array

```
@ComponentScan({"com.in28minutes.springboot.basics.springbootin10steps","com.in28minutes.springboot.somethingelse"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootIn10StepsApplication {...}
```

**Approach 2: Non-Spring Boot Project**

**Option 1:**

```
@ComponentScan(“com.in28minutes)
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {...}
```

**Option 2:**

```
@ComponentScan({"com.in28minutes.package1","com.in28minutes.package2"})
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {...}
```

**XML application context:**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.in28minutes" />
```

**Specific multiple packages:**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.in28minutes.package1, com.in28minutes.package2" />
```

Answer (score 5):

The IoC (Inversion of Control) container, represented in Spring by the class `ApplicationContext`, is the brain behind all of it. It all comes down to using reflection in a really powerful way.

To simplify, let's consider the following steps (all done through reflection):

1. Search all classes in the classpath
2. From those classes, get all classes annotated with `@Component`
3. For each class annotated with `@Component`, create a new instance of that class
4. Check for dependencies, i.e, for each created instance, check all fields annotated with `@Autowired` and create an instance for each one of them.
5. Keep everything in the context so they can be used later.

The remaining of this answer is an **oversimplified** version of how this happens as if we did it ourselves. Thankfully, Spring exists and we don't need to do this ourselves.

**The annotations**

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Node {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Wire { }
```

**Some annotated classes for testing**

```java
@Node
public class ServiceA {
    @Wire
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    public void doAStuff() {
        System.out.println("A stuff");
        serviceB.doBStuff();
    }
}

@Node
public class ServiceB {
    public void doBStuff() {
        System.out.println("B stuff");
    }
}
```

**The IoC Container**

```java
import org.reflections.Reflections;
/* dependency org.reflections:reflections:0.9.12 */

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class IoC {
    private final Map<Class<?>, Object> allNodes = new HashMap<>();

    public void start() {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(IoC.class.getPackageName());
        Set<Class<?>> nodeClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Node.class);

        try {
            for (Class<?> c : nodeClasses) {
                Object thisInstance = c.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

                for (Field f : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    if (f.getDeclaredAnnotation(Wire.class) != null) {
                        Object o = f.getType().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
                        f.set(thisInstance, f.getType().cast(o));
                    }
                }

                allNodes.put(c, thisInstance);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public <T> T getNodeByType(Class<T> cls) {
        return cls.cast(allNodes.get(cls));
    }
}
```

And the main class to get it all started.

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IoC ioc = new IoC();
        ioc.start();

        ServiceA serviceA = ioc.getNodeByType(ServiceA.class);
        serviceA.doAStuff();
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
A stuff
B stuff
```

Of course, Spring is a lot more powerful (and robust) than this. It allows for custom package scanning using `@ComponentScan`, beans of the same type with different names, singleton/prototype scoped beans, constructor wiring, properties files injection, amongst many other things. When it comes to Spring Boot, the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation make sure it finds and wire all `@Controller` annotated classes and set up a Netty/Jetty/Tomcat embedded server to listen to the requests and redirect to the proper controller based on the annotated types.

Answer (score 1):

Well where to search for the beans is defined by the [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-filters) which can be annotated on the `@Configuration` class that is used to bootstrap Spring.

For example , it has an attribute called `scanBasePackages` which tells Spring to scan the beans (A class that is annotated with `@Component` or its sterotypes such as `@Service` , `@Repository` , `@Controller` etc. ) from certain packages and its sub-packages only.

Then for each bean that are registered , it goes on see if there are any methods annotation with `@Bean`.If yes, also register them as beans.