# Field xyz in abc required a bean of type dfg that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I am new to spring boot and want to design my own APIs and test them with Postman client. However, I can't get past the following error.

[image]

Any opinions on this one? I found similar topics but none of them fix my problem.

I also give you my controller, model, and service classes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I believe I clearly initialized LectureService reference by using @Autowired annotation. This error keeps bugging me.

Note: I also added

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "io.theBMan.springBootStarter.lecture"
})
```

to my App.java class but didn't help as well.

Comment: You've autowired the service inside controller code but have not annotated the service class with @Service. That is the cause of this issue

Comment: You are the best! Can't thank enough buddy.

Comment: Glad to hear that the problem got resolved and thank you for your kind words :)

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran Please don't add answers as comments. Go ahead and add your answer as the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Adding the answer here as Simon suggested.

You've autowired the service inside controller code but have not annotated the service class with @Service. That is the cause of this issue.

Note:
The following stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3153617/3981539) beautifully explains about how and why both classes ( in your case LectureService and LectureController) should be defined to live in the application context. It is an excellent read.